# How to secure methods of composition?

Tags: java, methods, composition

I have `PC` class and `Monitor` class. 
How to secure method of class monitor that you could not use it when the PC is switched off  (status)?

```
public class Pc {
private Case theCase;
private Monitor theMonitor;
private Motherboard theMotherboard;
private boolean status;

public void turnOn(){
    System.out.println("Pc turned on!");
    status = true;
}
public void turnOff(){
    System.out.println("Pc turned off!");
    status = false;
}
```

and inside `Monitor` class

```
public void drawPixelArt(int heigh, int width, String color){
    System.out.println("Drawing pixel at " + heigh + " x "+ width + " px.");
}
```

So when `(status == false)` I do not want to be able to call any method.

e.g `thePc.getTheMonitor().drawPixelArt(1200, 1000, "RED");`

`getTheMonitor()` returns `Object`, so I can't try catch it.

Can someone help me how to deal with it?

Comment: I could use private getters, and then with other method check PC status, but maybe there is another answer.. I'm still learning, so please be tolerant ; )

Comment: FYI, this is where AOP (aspect-oriented programming) models can be of good use. In more complex frameworks, you could do this via interceptors. In a rather simple program, the accepted answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have properly designed the PC object as an aggregate of its parts, using the composition relationship between them.  However, the weak point here is to give access to the actual components, since it makes possible to violate the invariants you have placed yourself (for example, you cannot draw in the Monitor unless the PC is turned on, which makes perfect sense).

Maybe you would like to hide the details of the components and offer a unified interface to every operation through the PC object, implementing in some way a Facade pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Comment: Offcourse that make sense. I would try to implement version 1.2 with that pattern.  **Thanks for the advice.** ; )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `Monitor` can only be accessed through `getTheMonitor()` from your class `PC`, you could wrap your `Monitor` instance into a decorator that will check if the `status` is `true` and if not it could throw and exception or simply ignore the call.

The **inner class** to put into your class `Pc`:

```
private class MonitorStatusAware implements Monitor {
    public void drawPixelArt(int heigh, int width, String color){
        if (status) {
            theMonitor.drawPixelArt(heigh, width, color)
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The pc is switched off")
        }
    }
}
```

Then your method `getTheMonitor()` would be:

```
public Monitor getMonitor() {
    return new MonitorStatusAware();
}
```

This assumes that you have an interface in common between `MonitorStatusAware` and `Monitor` in which you have the method `drawPixelArt`, in this example I assumes that `Monitor` is your interface.

Comment: Yes it's the best for my needs. Thank you so much. ; )

Answer (score 0):

If you are bound to this design, you could check the status within the getter of the monitor and throw an IllegalStateException or so.

Comment: I do it for the needs of science. I just acted like you said .